# What is narrowing cast when I use initializer list?

Tags: c++, initialization, initializer-list

One guy tell me that more effective to write

```
SomeType val{another_val};
```

than

```
SomeType val = another_val;
```

cause in the second case we have narrowing cast.

Can you explain what is this? And is this true that initialize with initializer list more effective?

Comment: In [narrowing conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) section, it says that "list-initialization limits the allowed implicit conversions". So, I would say that it is safer. Although, I guess that if you use the second way, the compiler will give you warnings on those cases

Comment: The correct term here is narrowing **conversion**. There are no casts in this code. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using braces is another way of making your code safer, that's all. For example

```
int main() {
    unsigned n = -1.0; // hopefully a compiler warning, undefined behaviour
    unsigned m {-1.0}; // certainly a compiler diagnostic
}
```